# How to properly format a string with 2 integers in java

Tags: java, string, format, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I receive a string of form similar to "%value1% - %value2% interval" and I have two integers let's say v1, and v2, and the two values have to substitute the corresponding fields and the String to look in the end "v1 - v2 interval"
I tried the following:

```
StringBuilder valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
valueBuilder.append("%value1% - %value2% interval");
ageBuilder.append(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%1$d - %2$d interval", value1, value2))
```

I cannot modify the initial "%value1% - %value2% interval" part of the string! I can only substitute %value1% and %value2% from it that I receive like that

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you check System.out.printf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method:

```
StringBuilder valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
int v1 = 10;
int v2 = 20;
valueBuilder.append(
        "%value1% - %value2% interval"
        .replace("%value1%", String.valueOf(v1))
        .replace("%value2%", String.valueOf(v2))
);
System.out.println(valueBuilder);
```

output:

```
10 - 20 interval
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to use specifiers to insert the variables into the string.

```java
int value1 = 1;
int value2 = 2;

StringBuilder valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
valueBuilder.append(" ");
ageBuilder.append(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "v%d - v%d interval", value1, value2))
```

The `%d` will be replaced with the `value1` and `value2`.

#### Output from the `String.format()`

```
v1 - v2 interval
```

See more here: https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
    int value1 = 11, value2 =12;
    String formattedString = String.format("%s %d - %d", Locale.getDefault(), value1, value2);
    System.out.println(formattedString);
```

output is

```
en_US 11 - 12
```